# Internal Server Error with Django and uWSGI

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am trying to follow the steps in this guide: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Before I even get to the nginx part I am trying to make sure that uWSGI works correctly

my folder structure is srv/www/domain/projectdatabank/

the project databank folder contains my manage.py file

my wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

do you need to see my settings.py?

i get the following error when i point myself to the browser:

`-- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 10165|app: -1|req: -1/1] 66.56.35.151 () {38 vars in 681 bytes} [Tue Jul  9 18:19:46 2013] GET /admin/ => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 1 headers in 57 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 10165|app: -1|req: -1/2] 66.56.35.151 () {36 vars in 638 bytes} [Tue Jul  9 18:19:49 2013] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 1 headers in 57 bytes (0 switches on core 0)`

Now when I check my uWGI log it is just the same as above.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have solved this

in my original command line did not include full path to the wsgi.py file to run uWSGI

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /srv/www/databankinfo.com/projectdatabank/ --wsgi-file wsgi.py
```

to this

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --chdir /srv/www/databankinfo.com/projectdatabank/ --wsgi-file full/path/wsgi.py
```

and it worked

Comment: I find myself wondering why this happen tho, since no-one else asked maybe its obvious but to me its not, why did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 50):

For others debugging this same error, there is another possibility: an exception is being thrown by your `uwsgi.py`. To test this, open a django shell in your app directly with `python manage.py shell` and import your `uwsgi.py` (use the same path as in your `uwsgi.ini`).

Comment: @AlexVanLiew it's completely appropriate to add more information to debug problems. The existing answers only address one possible error (paths).  Who are you to judge what people should contribute to SO?

Comment: An error message *is* being thrown by uwsgi, which is "no python application found". The only reason that would be thrown is if, in fact, no python application was found. Pretty much the only reason for that is the paths are wrong. I'm pretty sure that if `uwsgi.py` threw an error upon execution uwsgi would display that error message instead of saying it didn't find anything at all; that's what mod_wsgi does and the two are similar in purpose. I just don't feel this adds enough to warrant re-opening a two-year-old question, that's all.

Comment: Well, I just debugged this exact problem with the exact same error message in my log and it was because an exception was being thrown in uwsgi.py.  So, your intuition is wrong.

Comment: Interesting! That's very unusual, which makes it more notable. I'll retract my downvote, then; my apologies. EDIT: I can't unless the answer is edited. Do you mind if I edit the answer a bit to make it a little more clear?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew - SO is different than forums.  It's not inappropriate to [answer old questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/does-it-make-sense-to-answer-old-questions) here.  In fact, there is a [necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge.  If there is information to any question, answered or not, that may add value to future visitors, it should be added.  That's the whole purpose of a Q&A site.

Comment: An other problem that may cause this error message is **the db can't connect** properly. I just stumbled upon this and it was just that I forgot to add the password. The tricky part is that `manage.py dbshell` doesn't necessarily reveals this as it was using password from .pgpass (PostgreSQL)

Comment: Another vote for the extreme **usefulness** of this answer.  My error was with my logging configuration, not even uwsgi, @AlexVanLiew, and I get this same exact message.  I didn't think to just open a shell (didn't even have to import uwsgi).  UWSGI is _awful_ with errors and completely opaque, so anything that helps debug error messages that UWSGI raises is needed.

Comment: Is there a way to configure UWSGI to print the actual error to stdout

Comment: Thanks for the hint 'python manage.py shell' at least it helped me to find out the exact reason.

Answer (score 14):

Check out my blog post on deploying Django behind uwsgi http://blog.johannesklug.de/2012/11/27/deploying-django-behind-nginx-with-uwsgi-and-virtualenv/. I created an ini-File to setup uwsgi, which points to the app callable with the parameter `module=project.wsgi:application`.

The whole file reads something like this:

```
(env)[project@host ~]$ cat uwsgi.ini 
[uwsgi]
# path to where you put your project code
chdir=/home/project/project
 
# python path to the wsgi module, check if you have one
module=project.wsgi:application
 
# this switch tells uwsgi to spawn a master process,
# that will dynamically spawn new child processes for
# server requests
master=True
# uwsgi stores the pid of your master process here
pidfile=/home/project/master.pid
vacuum=True
# path to your virtual environment
home=/home/project/env/
# path to log file
daemonize=/home/project/log
# this is where you need to point nginx to,
# if you chose to put this in project home make
# sure the home dir is readable and executable by
# nginx
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
 
### SEE UPDATE NOTICE FOR THIS ONE
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
```

Please note that I'm using virtualenv.

You might also be missing the lines

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

in your `wsgi.py`

Answer (score 0):

Check if u deleted any **init**.py file from the Djano apps. As django uses them to know which folders are apps, so they are kind of important.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ ini file for the site I was running had the word "module" misspelled as "modeule". Check that file carefully if you see htis ereror.

Answer (score 0):

In `uwsgi.ini`

Make sure you have set the right `module`.

```
[uwsgi]
module = yourapp.wsgi:application
...
```