# Internal Server Error with Django and uWSGI 2 Emperor mode

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have been trying to read everything I can find concerning this issue (and have learned much while doing so). The closest link I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555699/internal-server-error-with-django-and-uwsgi) and  [here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/263). My issue is almost identical except I'm running uwsgi exclusively in emperor mode. When I run uswsgi services WITHOUT running it in emperor mode my django website runs just fine. No matter how I change my configuration I always get the error message my /tmp/uwsgi.log file: "--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---" I have listed my configuration and error log below:

OS version: Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #538 armv6l GNU/Linux 
Django version: 1.6.5 
uwsgi version: 2.0.5.1

Virtual environment: /var/www/testbed/env 
Project location: /var/www/testbed/project/auth 
project tree:

```
./auth/
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- requirements.txt
|-- settings.py
|-- settings.pyc
|-- urls.py
|-- urls.pyc
|-- wsgi.py
`-- wsgi.pyc
```

file wsgi.py:

```
"""
WSGI config for auth project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

    import os, sys, site

    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))
    sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7')
    sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "auth.settings")

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

file /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
logto = /tmp/uwsgi.log
```

file /etc/uwsgi/vessals/auth.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
#plugins = python
# Django-related settings
chdir           =/var/www/testbed/project/auth
module          = auth.wsgi:application

# the virtualenv (full path)
home            =/var/www/testbed/env
virtualenv      =/var/www/testbed/env

# process-related settings
enable-threads  = true
pythonpath      = /var/www/testbed/project/auth
#wsgi-file      = /var/www/testbed/project/auth/auth/wsgi.py
env             = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=auth.settings

mount = /testbed/auth/admin=/var/www/testbed/project/auth/auth/wsgi.py
manage-script-name = true
#route-run = log:SCRIPT_NAME=${SCRIPT_NAME}

# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 1 #Simple rule is # of cores on machine
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /var/www/testbed/project/auth/uwsgi.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
logto           = /tmp/uwsgi.log
```

Command being executed listed below:

```
/var/www/testbed/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ --http :8000  --plugin python --binary-pathusr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

Error file /tmp/uwsgi.log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.5.1 (32bit) on [Tue Jun 10 19:06:12 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 10 June 2014 01:41:52
os: Linux-3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013
nodename: raspberrypi
machine: armv6l
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your processes number limit is 3376
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 6
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:57524 (port auto-assigned) fd 5
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)  [GCC 4.6.3]
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 8) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from auth.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.5.1 (32bit) on [Tue Jun 10 19:06:12 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 09 June 2014 23:07:00
os: Linux-3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013
nodename: raspberrypi
machine: armv6l
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your processes number limit is 3376
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/www/testbed/project/auth/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/testbed/env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1dca830
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 128512 bytes (125 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 23068)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 23071, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 23072)
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x616918
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 128512 bytes (125 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /var/www/testbed/project/auth/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x616918 pid: 23070 (default app)
mounting /var/www/testbed/project/auth/auth/wsgi.py on /testbed/auth/admin
added /var/www/testbed/project/auth/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 1 (mountpoint='/testbed/auth/admin') ready in 3 seconds on interpreter 0x9c6218 pid: 23070
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 23070)
Tue Jun 10 19:06:18 2014 - [emperor] vassal auth.ini has been spawned
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 23073, cores: 1)
Tue Jun 10 19:06:18 2014 - [emperor] vassal auth.ini is ready to accept requests
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 23071|app: -1|req: -1/1] 192.168.1.6 () {38 vars in 742 bytes} [Tue Jun 10 19:07:11 2014] GET /testbed/auth/admin => generated 21 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 23071|app: -1|req: -1/2] 192.168.1.6 () {36 vars in 626 bytes} [Tue Jun 10 19:07:11 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 23071|app: -1|req: -1/3] 192.168.1.6 () {38 vars in 742 bytes} [Tue Jun 10 19:07:13 2014] GET /testbed/auth/admin => generated 21 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 23071|app: -1|req: -1/4] 192.168.1.6 () {36 vars in 626 bytes} [Tue Jun 10 19:07:13 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

At this point, I'm grasping at straws. Out of all the reading that I have done I can't see why this keeps rendering  the "Internal Server Error."  I may have over looked something that why I've finally given in to my pride by posting my sorrows here.  Since I've gotten this far I really do think that I have overlooked something very small.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same error. Where you able to solve it ?

Comment: I just had the same issue and it was a result of not having Django installed. I was working in a new vagrant environment and sure enough a "pip install django" did the trick.

Comment: If this is still unsolved: I often had permission problems that were solved by manually setting the group and user (in my case `--uid www-data --gid www-data`), a la this guide: http://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!  - uwsgi say you, where problem

Comment: it says it cant load the python code , are you sure you addressed wsgi.py correctly?  set DEBUG to True temporary and update question with django log

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue several times in my deployments with usgi-emperor an the problem was that I didn't set the correct ALLOWED_HOSTS in my Django's project config file

In your config you shold have

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=[ "yourdomain.com", "other.domain.com" ]
```

or this (**discouraged because of security concerns, use at your own risk**):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]
```

to allow any host

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: I would suggest to add a note for "copying/pasting" readers that the asterisk solution is **strongly** discouraged, unless you know what you are doing.